# cgi page with #!/:0 at the end of URL

Tags: perl, url, cgi

I am coding for a perl/cgi webpage. Can anyone explain what does this url mean?

```
http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi#!/:0
```

What I am reading is starting from `#` sign, everything afterwards is an html item and it will not be sent to server. And, then I am confused. Thanks.

Update:

Seems the items at back of the URL is created explicitly by the cgi code itself. Thanks (or maybe sorry to) everyone who used brain cell on it.

Comment: Where and how did you encounter this? `#!/:0` looks like a shebang line and I am wondering if there is some vulnerability somewhere that this is trying to take advantage of (especially if the actual URL is `http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi?%23!/:0`).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an anchor (a reference to a part of the website). Please have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Anchor (NB: this url contains an anchor, too)